# Python 2.7 subprocess: get stdout, set timeout and use env variables

Tags: python-2.7, shell, timeout, subprocess, stdout

I'm using `subprocess.Popen()` to start a *subprocess* and get output using the `communicate()` method.  I tried to implement a timeout approx. as follows (I don't have the actual copy at the moment):

```
while p.poll() != 0 and theres_still_time():
    sleep(1)
p.kill()
out,err=p.communicate()
```

It looks odd to call `p.communicate()` after `p.kill()`.  While it doesn't throw an error, it doesn't appear to actually close the process on time.

Is there a way to:

- get stdout and stderr
- set a timeout
- execute from shell

all on the same process in python 2.7 on windows 8.1?

Executing from a shell wouldn't be necessary if the solution could use enviroment variables (particularly the path variable).